# Query nested documents with C# MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

I have a document called `Record` which contains an `Athlete` as a nested document. The structure looks like this in JSON:

```
{
  "Id": "000000000000000000000000",
  "Description": "sample string 1",
  "Athlete": {
    "Id": "123456789101112131415161",
    "Name": "sample string 2",
    "Username": "sample string 3",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

How do you query this structure to retrieve the `Record` object based on the `Athlete.Id`? I.E. If i have the ID of the athlete and I want to retrieve their record, how would you do this?

Answer (score 6):

**Way 1** : Using raw BsonDocument: (it will return list of `BsonDocument`)

```
var queryString = Query.EQ("Athlete.Id", "123456789101112131415161");
var resultBsons = collection.Find(queryString).ToList();
```

**Way 2** : Another way is using Typed version of mongodb c# driver:

define 2 classes:

```
public class Athlete
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Athlete Athlete { get; set; }
}
```

then do your query

```
var url = new MongoUrl("mongodb://localhost");
var client = new MongoClient(url);
var server = client.GetServer();
var database = server.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Record>("records");

var query = Query<Record>.EQ(i => i.Athlete.Id, "123456789101112131415161");
var result = collection.Find(query).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Beside what was already said, this [blog](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/05/27/using-elemmatch-in-a-mongodb-query.aspx) could help you with more complex situations. Basically it could look like:

```
records.Find(
  Query.ElemMatch("Athlete",
  Query.EQ("Id", athleteId)
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query by a sub-document field using exactly the format you provided: `Athlete.Id`.

```
db.collection_name.findOne({"Athlete.Id": "123456789101112131415161"})
```

EDIT: To do this in C#, you can do something like this assuming you defined the structure of a Record document in a class called `Record`:

```
IMongoQuery query = Query.EQ("Athlete.Id", "123456789101112131415161");
Record result = collection_name.FindOne(query);
```

Or if multiple documents may be returned with that matching Id:

```
IMongoQuery query = Query.EQ("Athlete.Id", "123456789101112131415161");
MongoCursor<Record> resultCursor = collection_name.FindOne(query);
```